# strcat, send char (text) to argument in function - c

Tags: c, function, char, arguments, strcat

I send `&s` and `char array(text)` in function `str_cpy`

```
void str_cpy(char *str_in, char *str_out);
```

Examle(work):

```
   void str_cpy(char *str_in, char *str_out);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *s = NULL;
   str_cpy(&s, "Hola Hola");
   puts(&s);
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}

void str_cpy(char *str_in, char *str_out) {
   strcat(str_in, "Hello");
}
```

Don't works (how it should work)

```
void str_cpy(char *str_in, char *str_out);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *s = NULL;
   str_cpy(&s, "Hola Hola");
   puts(&s);
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}

void str_cpy(char *str_in, char *str_out) {
   strcat(str_in, str_out);
}
```

How i can write last function? How correctly write function str_cpy or how send char array in function?

Comment: It's actually not legal to define your own functions using names that start with `str`; all such names are reserved. Most compilers won't  care but I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: help me please! I can't find info about this!

Comment: @unwind How i can write it correctly?

Comment: The usual beginner problem is that you really can't do any string handling in C before you understand arrays and pointers.

Comment: @unwind Actually, all names beginning with `str` _and a lowercase letter_ are reserved. The names I see in the above code all look valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of them would work. You need to allocate memory for `s`. Something like:

```
void str_cpy(char *str_in, char *str_out);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *s = calloc(sizeof(char), 100); //for 100 chars string
   //OR char s[100] = { 0 };

   //------v pass s not &s
   str_cpy(s, "Hola Hola");
   puts(s);   //similary use s not &s
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}

void str_cpy(char *str_in, char *str_out) {
   strcat(str_in, str_out);
}
```

Comment: void str_cpy(char *str_in, char *str_out) {
    strcat(str_in, str_out);
} - it's correctly?

Comment: why I can't to allocate 1 memory for s? char s[1] = { 0 };

Comment: @Zai4ik, yes that ok, if your `str_in` is initialized as empty string which is in my code. `chars[1]` creates array with size 1, I don't think you want that.

Comment: And remember to call `free()` when you are done using the variable, or you will be creating memory leaks. And even though most operative systems clears the heap once your program is done, it is sloppy practice not to clean up your own mess.

Comment: @Zai4ik That is not "1 memory", it is one byte of memory, which is not large enough to hold the string. You could allocate _sufficient_ memory however, like `char s[100];`. It is a most often better and safer than using calloc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an already alocated variable.
The problem here is, when using a Pointer like:

```
char *pointer = NULL;
```

You're not having any physical memory address properly pointed.
What you can do:

```
char string[32];
char *pointer;

pointer = string; // or pointer = &string[0], which is the same
str_cpy(pointer, "Something");
// Here, pointer holds a real address, so you can work with it.
```

If you dont want to use 2 variables, you can alocate memory for it.

```
char *pointer;
pointer = (char *) malloc(strlen("Something")+1); 
// Dont forget an extra byte for binary zero who will termine the string
// from now, pointer holds the address of a memory block. It means you can:
strcpy(pointer, "Something");
```